# Typescript issue with using multiple types

Tags: javascript, typescript

Been racking my brain for hours on this, basically, I have a bunch of different types defined like this:

```
export type SharedAPIProps = {
  id: string;
};

export type ButtonAPIProps = SharedAPIProps & {
  type: "paragraph--button";
  field_title: string;
};

export type SlideAPIProps = SharedAPIProps & {
  type: "paragraph--slide";
  field_slides: []
};

export type allAvailableComponents = ButtonAPIProps | SlideAPIProps;


export type ButtonProps = {
  title: string;
}

export type SlideProps = {
  slides: [];
} 

export type allCleanedProps = ButtonProps | SlideProps;
```

Then I have a function to convert an API response to a clean version:

```
export const toCleanProps = (component: allAvailableComponents): allCleanedProps => {
  const { type } = component;
  
  const convertedProps: allCleanedProps = {} as allCleanedProps;

  switch (type) {
    case "paragraph--button":
      convertedProps.title = component.field_title;
      break;
    case "paragraph--slide":
      convertedProps.slides = component.field_slides;
      break;
  }

  return convertedProps;
}
```

The issue is I'm getting Typescript errors on every property of the `convertedProps`. When I have just a single type defined in `allComponentProps` like:

```
export type allAvailableComponents = ButtonAPIProps;
```

I don't get the errors on the `paragraph--button` `convertedProps` properties, but of course do on the `paragraph--slide` `convertedProps` properties.

New to Typescript, so bear with me, I'm probably missing something simple here and tried a bunch of different things, but none work.

Error message being those props don't exist on the defined types.

Here's the complete example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKALAhlYATAQQAUBJIqCMAZzgF44BvAKDjgEs8AuOKmKNgHYBzANxMAvmKahIsBMlQAhAK4wYEAcTIVqddNlyFS5SjQBkjFvJTcARGBxYhULGAwBadwCNV6gbbFWADM2YAAbPAB9GDYYMOBuXn5hMUkmaXBoeCQUdDCOYC0TXXpMHHwinXNLVhyEuHtHZ1cPdyp8vGAAqxDwqPaCqm4AbQBdCSkZLOtULDCwggA3LDYwrC94gGEIAFtIAWABGBp6FTUNStM4AB88gsvqKQzZbIU4M79ik5qEWPjEviCUQSdJTOR1O6dL56ZisAadIZwMapOCgzLgt5zMKbeJYA54aGnXwaaG3NAdYBfSbo+AAYw0vAQEBxwDxhLgAAp6XsNIcYNwsUsVmsNsBtjyDkcqABKAXzFl4-CEgB8P3pAkZDBmcHEem5+z5gVRrHVjPVi2AsCVVTl2Nx+PZDF1WBoWIVDqqUjhAHdYrSMJy6tKfiaXahGi5mm5PD5zv5OFZWCaNBarQSqgA6GJxVD0fW8o4Z3oRaJ-YBGpNwLy4LAAawrcFpYYaDkjLmjbQptgTleTAlTMGtpgz8OA33zkpgRdCJdHVAbrGrrPrVnE6VYuBgyigAkbKctg-TplSQA

Comment: `slides` is an array. Try using push

Comment: Sorry, typo, I've updated the SharedProps to SharedAPIProps

Comment: And also please share the *exact* error messages you receive

Comment: @T.J.Crowder another type, updated accordingly

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry again, another typo, I've updated it. Example is a much more simplified version and tried to make it simple to understand and clear about the issue I've having

Comment: @derpirscher updated the post, all errors are related to typescript saying the props haven't been defined on the types

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message. Don't describe it. Copy and paste it. And I wonder how something like `const convertedProps: allCleanedProps = {}` would work without error. Because every instance of `allCleanedProps` must have either a`title` or a `slides` property

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's awesome, wasn't aware of that resource. I've updated the post with a link to the code.

Comment: @derpirscher See the code link I just updated, it shows the exact errors there, i.e. ```Property 'slides' does not exist on type 'allCleanedProps'.```

Comment: @derpirscher changing to ```const convertedProps: allCleanedProps = {}``` gives you another error: ```Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'allCleanedProps'.```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant in my comment (because that `as allCleanedProps` wasn't there yet when I posted that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that narrowing the type of `component` doesn't narrow the type of `convertedProps`, so TypeScript doesn't know that the assignments are okay.

You can fix it by creating `componentProps` in the branches:

```typescript
export const toCleanProps = (component: allAvailableComponents): allCleanedProps => {
  const { type } = component;

  let convertedProps: allCleanedProps;

  switch (type) {
    case "paragraph--button":
      convertedProps = {
        title: component.field_title,
      };
      break;
    case "paragraph--slide":
      convertedProps = {
        slides: component.field_slides,
      };
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unexpected 'type'`);
  }

  return convertedProps;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-YAAGkjUbSydYXlwWAA1oEoz6-Q0HIGXMG2uTbBHy3A1WaLfiqtCS8m4cAERmJTAc6E86OqMXu2Xy5WWbWS50glhlGE+cOEBgKI64AcjwBRKAUKDsgAGAFUDuBgDS43g4AByOpv69SuviB1wXAYGUKABB7GN+3tcQgA)

If the cleanup process is involved, you could split it off into helper functions:

```typescript
const cleanButtonProps = (component: ButtonAPIProps): ButtonProps => {
  return {
    title: component.field_title,
  };
};
const cleanSlideProps = (component: SlideAPIProps): SlideProps => {
  return {
    slides: component.field_slides,
  };
};

export const toCleanProps = (component: allAvailableComponents): allCleanedProps => {
  const { type } = component;

  let convertedProps: allCleanedProps;

  switch (type) {
    case "paragraph--button":
      convertedProps = cleanButtonProps(component);
      break;
    case "paragraph--slide":
      convertedProps = cleanSlideProps(component);
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unexpected 'type'`);
  }

  return convertedProps;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-k4VlYrGN-cH+KzZtx-M+tvLPKFgSPrC8uCwAGtH8fV+uHJuXNu2nJWwDyfY8+wHGBxxKelGSdD1TFve0YAfQ8jxfc0P1QzogiwZQwl5VDagwCgpzgA5SIAUSgCgoDZAADABVA5wGAKlILwOAAHI6k4uiUPjdJWD9eV6XAs9KQkIA)